# Xcode - How to combine key and value into single array?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, nsarray

I have a JSON array being pulled into XCode with a key and value. I can get the keys. I can get the values. But is there an easy way to combine them into a single array?

The following code works, but I end up with two separate arrays (channels and channelKeys).

This seems like an inelegant way to create a single array which contains both the key and its value.

```
-(void) convertArray : (NSMutableArray *)data{

    // Set data
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [data objectAtIndex:0];

    for (NSString *key in [dic allKeys]) {
        [channels addObject:[dic objectForKey:key]];
    }

    // Set Key Array

    NSMutableDictionary *dic3 = [data objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *keys = [dic3 allKeys];

    [channelKeys addObjectsFromArray: keys];

}
```

Comment: Are `channels` and `channelKeys` supposed to be the same array? It looks like you are trying to store the array in the form `[value1, value2, value3, key1, key2, key3]`. Is that your intention?

Comment: This seems like a foolish thing to do, vs simply keeping the values in a dictionary. (And, BTW, a "JSON array" does not contain keys and values -- that's a "JSON object".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create an array of the form [key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3...] then try something like the following (recall that keys are not restricted to NSStrings)

```
for (id key in [dic allKeys]) {
    [resultArray addObject:key];
    [resultArray addObject:[dic objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: For reference, you can simply do "for (id key in dic)". Iterating on a dictionary returns the keys by default.